# Reconstruct a tree from a list, with depth info encapsulated in the entry of list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

We built a list from a tree (**not** necessarily a binary search tree) via `depth first traversal`.

Each entry inside is a pair `(k, d)`, k is the key of a node and d is the depth of that node.

Now we need to construct the original tree back from the list.

How do we do it?

---

Note

1. tree is not necessarily a binary search tree
2. we do not know whether the depth first traversal is `pre-order`, `in-order` or `post-order`.

---

My question is

- Can we achieve this reverse engineering under the conditions? I know for binary search tree, we need at least two traversal lists (e.g., inorder and postorder list) to reconstruct the original tree.

  - How? if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Things to note:**

- The in-order traversal produces a unique tree
- The pre-order and post-order don't:

  You can't differentiate between these two:

  ```
    1    1
   /      \
  2        2
  ```

  I'll just generate the one on the left (doing this makes it a lot easier).

**What we can say right away:**

- If the first node is the root (i.e. not depth 0):

  We're either doing in-order with an empty left subtree, or pre-order.
- If the last node is the root:

  We're either doing in-order with an empty right subtree, or post-order.
- If neither of the above:

  We're doing in-order traversal.

For the two cases above where we don't know which traversal to do, the simplest approach is to try to generate the trees for both possible traversals, and discard whichever one doesn't work (based on the below restrictions), if either.

**Some restrictions:**

For in-order, we can't go right or up if the current node is empty.

For pre-order, we can't go left or right if the current node is empty.

For post-order, we have to go up after setting the current node - we can't go left or right without having set the current node.

In all cases, we try to go left before going right before going up.

By 'go left' or 'go right', I mean creating an (empty) left or right child and traversing to that node.
By 'go up', I mean simply traversing upwards in the already created tree.

Based on the above restrictions, it should be easy to write an algorithm to generate the tree. As an example for in-order:

1. If the new node's depth is deeper than the current node's depth:

   1. If the current node is empty and doesn't have a left child, we can just create a left child and set that as the current node
   2. Otherwise, if the current node is not empty and doesn't have a right child, we can just create a right child and set that as the current node
2. Otherwise, if the depth is the same as the current node and the current node is empty,
   set that node's value to the new node
3. If none of the above cases triggered and the current node is empty,
   set the parent of the current node as the current node
4. If none of the above cases triggered, fail
5. If 1.1, 1.2, or 3 triggered, repeat from 1.

**Example:**

Input: `(f, 2), (g, 2), (b, 1), (i, 2), (c, 1), (a, 0)`

Since `(a, 0)` is the root, we're doing either in-order or post-order.

So then we generate 2 subtrees:

```
in-order        post-order
    .                .
   /                /
  .                .
 /                /
f                f
```

(`.` indicates an empty node)

When we get `(g, 2)`, we can already discard the in-order tree, as we can't go right or up from `f`'s parent, because it is empty, so we're stuck.

Then we continue with post-order:

```
    .
   /
  .
 / \
f   g


    .
   /
  b
 / \
f   g


     .
   /   \
  b     .
 / \   /
f   g i


     .
   /   \
  b     c
 / \   /
f   g i


     a
   /   \
  b     c
 / \   /
f   g i
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by pre/post/in-order, a single DFS run with the depth data should allow you to reconstruct the tree if you know the time of first visiting each node (I guess that would amount to a "pre-order" by your definition). In-order isn't even defined well in non-binary trees (would the parent appear after the first node? after the second? what if there's a single child?)

If you can tell the order of discovering each node, you can just go over the list while the depth increases, creating more and more children (and keeping track of the **last** node encountered at each depth), and once you get a non increasing depth you know for sure how many levels up you need to go in order to place the next node.
Two list-consecutive nodes with the same depth would be siblings of the same parent, and in general, if the last node had depth d1 and you now encounter d2, then you need to go up d1-d2+1 levels back up the current branch before attaching the next node.

A depth of `d` is enough to identify the parent (it would have to be the last node of depth `d-1`), since in DFS you can't encounter any other parent of that depth without first completely exploring the entire branch descending from from the previous one.

A slightly better proof - let `v` be a node along your list of depth `d`. It would have to descend of some node of depth `d-1`.
Let's assume the list is

```
[(v0,d0), ... (v, d), ...]
```

The parent can't be in the remainder of the list since this means you reached a child before its parent - impossible while traversing a tree. So the parent has to be in the first `...` section. Let's assume it's not the last `d-1`-depth node prior to `v` - so let's say the list is -

```
[(v0,d0), ... (vi, d-1), ... (vj, d-1), ...(v, d), ...]
```

if `v` is the child of `vi`, than when traversing the original tree your DFS reached `vi`, missed `v` somehow, then passed to another branch originating from some ancestor of `vi`, found `vj` there, and only then came back to `vi` and encountered `v`. This violates the DFS premise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but:

- If the first pair in the sequence has depth zero, it's a pre-order traversal.
- If the last pair in the sequence has depth zero, it's a post-order traversal.
- Else it's an in-order traversal.

Comment: If the first pair in the sequence has depth zero, it can be in-order if the left subtree is empty. If the last pair in the sequence has depth zero, it can be in-order if the right subtree is empty. Also, knowing which traversal it is doesn't give you a solution yet.

Comment: Ah, good point about the empty subtrees. e: And now I see the problem with reconstructing the tree from an in-order traversal.